# how do I figure out why all messages go to dead letter queue? - Elastic beanstalk worker environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just started using a worker environment in elastic beanstalk. As I understand it, the environment listens to a queue then POSTs the message to a url that you specify. I created a POST endpoint and specified the url in the configure section of elasticbeanstalk.

However, when I send a message to the queue it isn't being posted to the instance. All of the messages go to the dead letter queue. When I click 'view messages' on the dead letter queue and poll, it shows all the messages, but no error or anything that would give me some hint as to why they're failing.

Does anyone have any tips on how to debug this?

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log` and possibly `/var/log/nginx/access.log` (if your application uses nginx) on the worker. You should get some information about the status of the requests.

Comment: I looked at /var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log and I keep getting something like this with different numbers and letters , I don't know what that is

http-err: 45ef1b59-5d6e-4f21-9bb0-e2e384e81da0 (15) 302 - 0.004

Comment: It's giving you a 302 redirect status.  Do you have forced SSL set up?  You need to exclude the path to the controller that the queue is hitting from your SSL configuration.

Comment: That could actually.
 Thank, I'll try that